# Convert a char with va_arg

Tags: c

I need to get from va_arg a char.
i use an integer, but my problem it's does not work !

```
char c = (char)va_arg(ap, int);
write(1, &c, 1);
```

it's gave the ascii code of something else.

Comment: char c = va_arg(ap, char) ?

Comment: @willll: No, that has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arguments to variadic functions (the ones corresponding to the `...` in the declaration) undergo the *default argument promotions*.

Integer arguments narrower than `int` are promoted to `int` (or to `unsigned int` if the type is unsigned and its maximum value exceeds `INT_MAX`), and arguments of type `float` are promoted to `double`.

So you *can't* get a `char` from `va_arg()`. The obvious

```
char c = va_arg(ap, char); // DON'T DO THIS
```

has undefined behavior.

What you're doing:

```
char c = (char)va_arg(ap, int);
```

looks correct, though the `(char)` cast is unnecessary; the `int` result will be implicitly converted to `char` anyway.

For example,this program's output is `c = 'x'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void func(int first, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, first);
    char c = va_arg(ap, int);
    va_end(ap);
    printf("c = '%c'\n", c);
}

int main(void) {
    func(42, 'x');
}
```

You need to update your question to describe what the actual problem is. You say "it's gave the ascii code of something else"; I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Nice terse "default argument promotions" explanation expect I think you can drop the "is unsigned and its".

Comment: @chux: Perhaps, but I wanted to emphasize that a narrow integer type can be promoted to `int` only if it's unsigned. For any narrow signed type, its maximum value cannot exceed `INT_MAX`.

Comment: IAC, I still like the shortness of the explanation (and was trying to squeeze a few more words out.)  OTOH:  Although 50 shy, congratulations on 100k!

Comment: @chux: Oh great, now you've jinxed it! 8-)} I'm now at the very top of the under-100,000 group. I'm about to be at the very bottom of the over-100,000 group.